# java - not able to use readFile() function

Tags: java, readfile

I am trying to use  readFile function from Container super class but I trigger FileNotFound exception under stack. What am I missing here?

```
public static final List<String> readFile(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        
        
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

        try (Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(fileName))) {
            while (s.hasNextLine()) {
                result.add(s.nextLine());
                s.close();
            }
            return result;
           
        }

            }
```

```
public Stack(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        
        stack = new ArrayList<String>();
        String obj = (String) Stack.readFile(fileName).get(0);
        stack.add(obj);
                        
                    if(obj.startsWith("Stack"))
                            {
                        stack.add(obj.substring(4).strip());
                    }
                }
```

try to read file under Stack function by using readFile function.

Comment: Well a file not found exception should be pretty clear, it can't find your file. How are you calling and running this? Also, putting readline in a loop and closing the scanner like that means you'll read one line and then close the file. Why is it in a loop?

Comment: Hi Elliot,

While loops reads each line of txt file and puts it into an an array.

Comment: My goal is call it from Stack which is subclass of Container. Container already has readFile method which reads the file. Do I need to read file under stack again?

Comment: "*Do I need to read file under stack again?*" -- No. You need to first fix the file not found exception. Your path to the file is probably wrong. You probably shouldn't even be using a file but rather should be using a resource.

Comment: Make sure you know the [current directory](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/91-find-the-current-directory-in-java) when you supply the path. And remove *s.close()*